# Minimum Xcode Dev Tools packages required for installing gems?

Tags: ruby, xcode, macos, rubygems

I'm running 10.5.8 and did not have the developer tools installed (I run mostly on my Linux partition)... but I was trying to dry run the installation of a ruby app, [timetrap](https://github.com/samg/timetrap), for a friend so that I could walk him through installation when we get together in a few weeks.

In any case, I kept getting failures of:

```
sudo gem install sqlite3
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
or 'yum install sqlite3-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
    --with-sqlite3-dir
    --without-sqlite3-dir
    --with-sqlite3-include
    --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
    --with-sqlite3-lib
    --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib   

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
```

I actually had sqlite3.h in `/usr/local/include` but could not get anything different even when trying `sudo gem install timetrap -- --with-sqlite3-include=/usr/local/include`. I tried installing [BitNami RubyStack](http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack) to see if that helped and no dice.

In any case, I ran into some posts (several here) saying that c libraries were required for some gems, so I decided to install XCode and everything worked.

XCode is a space hog and I'll hardly ever use it, but I'd like to be able to do what I need to with this. I tried installing only the gcc-4.2 package alone and got failures. I found that the package `MacOSX10.5.pkg` also did not sole the problem. Installing all of XCode (Build Tools Essentials and Unix Development options) takes 2+ GB.

It seems that just the gcc package should give me what I want, but something is awry.

Would someone suggest:
- if all of XCode really is required for some other thing included in that package?
- if installing XCode is setting a path/include variable somewhere such that it works when XCode gets installed but not when I try to do my a la carte install of gcc along?

I have several sqlite3.h's scattered around with these individual packages as well as the ones that were already there. What's my issue? Is it not really sqlite3.h but something else?

**Goal:** Install some basic package that lets me do this without needing various other tools I'll never use. I dual boot on an older MacBook and only have 10GB left on my drive. Without XCode I had closer to 13! I realize I could install and then just trash XCode, but it seems like while I'm at it, gcc isn't bad to have around.

Comment: I suggest you to postpone your problem until the free space gets below 7GB :p

Comment: I thought everyone was anal on this site? I just don't like extra stuff littered around :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XCode's installer has some options to let you strip out some things you won't use, but it's not going to let you strip everything and only keep gcc.

Remember their saying "It just works", well, they're not going to make it easy to break it.

Comment: Well, yes and no. XCode.mpkg proper has very few options. I was successful with selecting "Xcode Build Essentials" (something to that effect -- you can't unselect this one) and "Unix Development". I was using XCode 3.1.4 downloaded from Apple's site and there's a directory fo all available packages -- so what I want is to know what individual packages I need from there. Does that make sense? My theory is that 'Xcode Developer Essentials' is pulling some combination of individual packages -- which ones are essential for ruby gem installs? I don't need XCode or bluetooth.sdk for example...

Comment: Well, though not satisfying, I think your answer is correct. Installing via the actual Xcode.mpkg allows the "cleanest" implementation -- 1) almost everything is in /Developer and 2) the stuff that's not can be uninstalled via the command `sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all`. Installing the individual packages doesn't seem to set `$PATH` correctly and littered my system in the attempt. Again... not happy with the answer, but you're correct!